# CSS Bootstrap Carousel: Show controls when hover over control section, not when hovering over entire carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel has full page images, and when the mouse is anywhere on the page the controllers show up. I'd like them to only show up when hovering over the area that the controller is in.

```
.carousel .carousel-control {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { 
    visibility: hidden; 
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The third tag is to remove the gradient, any help is appreciated

Comment: Hit the F12 key on your keyboard, have a look at what the css is actually doing so that you know what you need to over-ride.

Answer (score 1):

Use opacity instead of visibility like so:

```
.carousel .carousel-control{
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-control:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to show you it working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6uxogbzt/)

Answer (score 1):

You just a little change of CSS:

```
.carousel .carousel-control {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel-control {
    visibility: visible;
}
```